# Does "I have been waiting for you" mean that "I am still waiting"?

Tags: tenses, present-progressive

Assume that I was waiting for someone for several hours and finally, he/she arrived to the meeting late. I wonder whether I say "I have been waiting for you", it means that I am still "waiting" or not.

I'm asking because this structure is known as Present Perfect Continues which basically is used for something that started in the past and still continues to the present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between Present Perfect and Present Perfect Continuous?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66894/is-there-any-difference-between-present-perfect-and-present-perfect-continuous)

Comment: There are many more related questions if you search [present perfect continuous](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=present+perfect+continuous).

Comment: You are right but I'm specifically asking for the verb "waiting".

Comment: What makes you think "waiting" and "other verbs" would lead to different interpretation? The answer to the question is crystal clear.

Comment: I was just wondering if the phrase sounds weird or the tense can be used so in "some" circumstances.

Comment: While the present perfect continuous usually means that the action is still ongoing, it can also be used when the action has just completed. That's what's going on here. Similarly: *I have been eating snacks all day, and now I'm not hungry for dinner.*