# Difference between present perfect simple and present perfect continuous

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-aspect, perfect-continuous

Are both "*I have read this book for months*" and "*I have been reading this book for months*" correct?
If yes, how are meanings different?

Comment: I'm struggling to find a context where "I have read this book for months" would sound at all acceptable. Perhaps "I have read this book for months at a time, in 1997-8, 2001, and 2011, and I still can't get to grips with all the concepts it discusses."

Comment: 'I have read this book for months' means that you finished reading it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect simple usually describes a recent completed event, but when used with "for" it could describe an event that is still going on.
Present perfect continuous usually describes either a recent past activity (you have been reading for months, now you are done). Or a continuous event (you have been reading for months and didn't finish yet).

TL;DR: in this case it could imply the same thing depending on your context. Check these two pages for more details:

[Present perfect simple - Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-simple-i-have-worked?q=Present%20perfect%20simple%3A%20uses)

[Present perfect continuous - Campridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-continuous-i-have-been-working?q=Present%20perfect%20continuous%3A%20uses)

Also, this question is actually a duplicate, [check here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66894/is-there-any-difference-between-present-perfect-and-present-perfect-continuous).